# PROLOG family tree: how can I output all the siblings and cousins?

Tags: prolog

Hi I am working on a PROLOG family tree question, and this is what I have so far:

```
/*1. Write Prolog clauses to express the following three relationships, 
 * given the parent/2 relationship: grandparent/2, sibling/2, cousin/2.*/

% clauses
parent(jill, amy).
parent(jill, tim).
parent(jill, john).
parent(amy, grace).
parent(amy, anna).
parent(tim, sam).
parent(tim, joel).
parent(tim, ben).

% rules
grandparent(X,Y) :- 
    parent(Z,Y), 
    parent(X,Z).
sibling(X, Y) :-
    parent(Z, X),
    parent(Z, Y).
cousin(X,Y) :- 
    parent(P, X), 
    parent(S, Y), 
    sibling(P, S).
```

When I put:

```
?- sibling(X, tim).
```

the output gives:

```
X = amy
```

but both john and amy are tim's sibling. The same problem happens with:

```
?- cousin(ben, X).
```

which gives:

```
X = grace
```

when both grace and anna are ben's cousins.
What changes do I need to make in order for the code to output all of tim's siblings and ben's cousins?
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you've got a little bug over there.
You should correct the sibling rule - just a small hint here, try to use the rule  as so

```
sibling(grace,grace)
```

and back to your issue, after you're getting first response click the `;` or any of these `; n r space TAB` keys, as the result you see is the first correct response. If you want to see the next correct result you need to use one of the keys above.

You can also try to use `findall` predicate to see all the results in the list

```
?- findall(X, cousin(grace, X),Z).
Z = [sam, joel, ben].
```

Comment: Will "sibling(X, Y) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    parent(Z, X),
    parent(Z, Y). " resolve the issue with the sibling rule?

Comment: Yea, exactly :)